# Tower of Hanoi using recursion Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

So I have found many topics here about the problem but I have my unique problems of course.

I have to implement a code in Python 3 which plays the game of Hanoi, using some graphical object named hanoi_game.

So my understanding of recursion is bad, I remember also my studying of this subject in high school, I have never really succeeded to catch it entirely, I find it difficult to think of a problem in a way of recursion.

So here is my code:

```
def play_hanoi(hanoi, n, src, dest, temp):
    if n == 1:
        hanoi.move(src, dest) 
    play_hanoi(hanoi, n - 1, src, temp, dest)
    play_hanoi(hanoi, 1, src, dest, temp)
    play_hanoi(hanoi, n - 1, temp, dest, src)
```

Firstly, I know I have here an algorithmic mistake, where a big disc is laid on a little one - I don't really know what is the problem because I don't catch the process well enough.

Secondly, what's going here?

Consider when we have n = 3:
We'll call the function with n = 2 where the destination now is the temporary rod, this n = 2 will call to n = 1, it triggers the base case which is in its turn moves the disc ahead of the last one.
Now it turns to (to my understanding):

```
    play_hanoi(hanoi, 1, src, dest, temp)
```

which moves the bigger one remained in source into the destination.

Now it turns to:

```
    play_hanoi(hanoi, n - 1, temp, dest, src)
```

where `n - 1 = 1`, and this one moves I think what we have in the temp rod into the destination, above the bigger one...

And so on...

I don't know what I understood incorrectly.

Thanks.

Comment: You need an `else:`, or else your `n` will recurse beyond 0 and into the negatives.

Comment: But once we have n = 1, we don't recurse again, we only do a move. No?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the rest of the code. :P You're creating three branches by calling `play_hanoi` three times in each function. Regardless of what `n` is, all three `play_hanoi` statements will execute.